# Is It Possible to copy and install windows 10 installation files manually?

Tags: installation, windows-update, windows-10

In recently windows 10 there was an option to install update through lan or home networked computer,So my assumption would be there would be some local location for installation,

Is it possible to manually copy and install  the "received windows 10 update" files manually from one computer to another?

Comment: Why not just download the media creation tool and make a USB and/or DVD installer?

Comment: Yes, then run the setup.exe.